# Dell SAS controllers & Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, dell, sas

Does anyone have any experience with the Dell SAS 5/iR and the SAS 6/iR controllers?  We are looking at virtualizing 5 of our servers and would like to hear about any experiences using either of these controllers in a RAID1 configuration with Hyper-V.  From what I can see the SAS 5 is likely a software RAID and therefore not suitable, but I’m not sure about the SAS 6.

Our guest OS’s will be (all Windows 2008)

1. Exchange 2007 (100 users)
2. BlackBerry Server (10 users)
3. Domain Controller
4. External Website (low traffic)
5. Proxy Server

EDIT:I found a link on the Dell site listing the processor for the SAS6/iR as an LSI LSISAS1068E 255 MHz. Can anyone confirm this as software RAID controller and where in the documentation that can be identified, I can't tell what feature would show it as a software RAID?  I need to be able to so show management the documentation identifying it as software RAID to justify the upgrade to a better controller.
 http://www.lsi.com/DistributionSystem/AssetDocument/files/docs/marketing_docs/storage_stand_prod/SCG_LSISAS1068E_PB_040407.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I found the SAS5/iR and SAS6/iR are hardware raid, but with no cache memory and a lower performance chip (LSI 1068 and LSI 1068e).  Though it seems to be argued both ways.  But end of the day if you need good performance on your contoller card, it won't come from the SAS5 or SAS6, go with the PERC.

Comment: Hello user26147, I've a IBM ServeRAID BR10i with the LSI 1068e chip. It's possible to flash it with the DELL Firmware to recover a lost RAID? The problem is that the BR10i is 1068e and the DELL Controller that we lost was the 5/iR, so it's the 1068 version.

Answer (score 1):

the i/R series is all fakeraid. go for sas6i.

Comment: Do you have a link to any Dell documents on this?  I haven't been able to find any myself.

Comment: Do you mean do with the PERC6i? I can't find a SAS6i on their site.

Comment: ah, sorry, I meant that the SASxxx series are all fakeraid, while the PERCs are real controllers. 

not sure about documentation, but you can call Dell support and ask for it. 

btw, since you're virtualising an IO heavy machine (Exchange especially), I wouldn't recommend you stay at raid1. For heavy IO you need a lot of spindles, preferraby raid10, but raid5 or 6 will do as well, with enough drives.